# (Python C API) PyRun_StringFlags missing builtin functions?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-embedding

I am trying to embed some python in my pet project. I have reduced my problem to the following code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "iostream"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject *globals = Py_BuildValue("{}");
    PyObject *locals = Py_BuildValue("{}");

    PyObject *string_result = PyRun_StringFlags(
        "a=5\n"
        "s='hello'\n"
        "d=dict()\n"
        ,
        Py_file_input, globals, locals, NULL);
    if ( PyErr_Occurred() ) {PyErr_Print();PyErr_Clear();return 1;}
    return 0;
}
```

(I know I'm not cleaning up any references. This is an example.)

it can be compiled by

```
c++ $(python-config --includes) $(python-config --libs) test.cpp -o test
```

If I run it I get the following error:

```
$ ./test 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'dict' is not defined
```

It seems the the builtin functions aren't loaded. I also cannot `import` anything. I get that `__import__` is missing. How can I load the missing modules or whatever I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way:

```
g = PyDict_New();
if (!g)
    return NULL;

PyDict_SetItemString(g, "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins());
```

And then pass `g` as `globals`.

Comment: Thanks! `PyEval_GetBuiltins` was exactly what I needed. I just didn't know how to find it.

Comment: I use this. But got `vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute` error in code `if not 'nickname' in vars(__builtins__):`

Answer (score 7):

You could also execute the code inside the `__main__` module namespace:

```
PyObject *globals = PyModule_GetDict(PyImport_AddModule("__main__"));
PyObject *obj = PyRun_String("...", Py_file_input, globals, globals);
Py_DECREF(obj);
```

This is in fact what [`PyRun_SimpleStringFlags`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/pythonrun.c#l1457) does internally.